# TensorFlow, Keras: Replace Activation layer in pretrained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, keras-2

I'm trying to replace swish activation with relu activation in pretrained TF model EfficientNetB0. EfficientNetB0 uses swish activation in Conv2D and Activation layers. This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030721/cant-change-activations-in-existing-keras-model) is very similar to what I'm looking for. I also found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51869717/6561141) which works for models without skip connection. Below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ReLU

def replace_swish_with_relu(model):
    '''
    Modify passed model by replacing swish activation with relu
    '''
    for layer in tuple(model.layers):
        layer_type = type(layer).__name__
        if hasattr(layer, 'activation') and layer.activation.__name__ == 'swish':
            print(layer_type, layer.activation.__name__)
            if layer_type == "Conv2D":
                # conv layer with swish activation.
                # Do something
                layer.activation = ReLU() # This didn't work
            else:
                # activation layer
                # Do something
                layer = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu', name=layer.name + "_relu") # This didn't work
    return model

# load pretrained efficientNet
model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(
    include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None,
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3), pooling=None, classes=1000,
    classifier_activation='softmax')

# convert swish activation to relu activation
model = replace_swish_with_relu(model)
model.save("efficientNet-relu")
```

How to modify `replace_swish_with_relu` to replace swish activations with relu in the passed model?

Thank you for any pointers/help.

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question here, the problem to me is not clear

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you, I have modified the post for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`layer.activation` points to `tf.keras.activations.swish` function address. We can modify it to point to `tf.keras.activations.relu`. Below is the modified, `replace_swish_with_relu`:

```
def replace_swish_with_relu(model):
    '''
    Modify passed model by replacing swish activation with relu
    '''
    for layer in tuple(model.layers):
        layer_type = type(layer).__name__
        if hasattr(layer, 'activation') and layer.activation.__name__ == 'swish':
            print(layer_type, layer.activation.__name__)
            if layer_type == "Conv2D":
                # conv layer with swish activation
                layer.activation = tf.keras.activations.relu
            else:
                # activation layer
                layer.activation = tf.keras.activations.relu
    return model
```

Note: If you are modifying the activation function, then you need to retrain the model to work with the new activation. [Related](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47208).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def replace_swish_with_relu(model):
    '''
    Modify passed model by replacing swish activation with relu
    '''
    for i,layer in enumerate(tuple(model.layers)):
        layer_type = type(layer).__name__
        if hasattr(layer, 'activation') and layer.activation.__name__ == 'swish':
            print(layer_type, layer.activation.__name__)
            if layer_type == "Conv2D":
                # conv layer with swish activation.
                # Do something
                model.layers[i] = ReLU() # This didn't work
            else:
                # activation layer
                # Do something
                model.layers[i] = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu', name=layer.name + "_relu") # This didn't work
    return model
```

Comment: This didn't work either. Thanks for your answer.