# replace swish layer with x*sigmoid(x) in tensorflow keras model

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have pre-trained TF model EfficientNetB0.
this model can not be converted to TF-lite since it has a swish activation.
therefore, I would like to replace the swish activation with X*sigmoid(X) function without changing the weights of the other layers.

I saw this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66242091/tensorflow-keras-replace-activation-layer-in-pretrained-model), it is close but not the right way to solve this since the new activation should contain the X output

Comment: What version of TF are you using?

Comment: tensorflow 2.10

Comment: Swish is supported in TFlite 2.10, it shouldn't be an issue. Are you sure this is your problem?

Comment: I look at the tflite operators at this list https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/op_select_allowlist  it is not include swish

Comment: TFLite supports natively the sigmoid (named logistic), and multiplication. The Converter will convert the swish automatically to those two ops. You should check first and foremost the [TFLite Native Ops](https://www.tensorflow.org/mlir/tfl_ops) support